# Kill the windows authentication session using Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, windows-authentication

I have developed asp.net application with windows authentication. Whenever user open the site, first time it is asking for windows username and password. I want to kill windows authentication session by clicking signout button.

> How to kill the windows authentication session without closing the browser?

Comment: I am new to this forum. I am don't know how to ask question here, Don't down vote, Help me to Improve....

Answer (score 1):

Try these links which provide means of clearing the session:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(v=vs.90).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.abandon(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you call Session.Abandon() the session is queued for deletion.
The sessionid is also stored in a cookie on the client. 
When the client makes a new call to the server with this sessionid, the server regenerates the session (making a new session with the same id). This makes it appear that the same session still exists.
In order to remove the cookie client side, use this code:

```
        if(Request.Cookies["SessionId_"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["SessionId_"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-10);
        }
        else if(Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-10);
        }
        Session.Abandon();
```